# QT Launch on background thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I'm new to QT and need to run a process on the background thread but am having a hard time:

```
        QApplication::setOverrideCursor(Qt::WaitCursor);
        window.connect();
        QCoreApplication::processEvents();
        QApplication::restoreOverrideCursor();
        window.show();
```

Currently the connect() function is blocking the UI, how can I wait for it without locking up the UI? connect() is making a reuqest to a server.

Comment: Please provide [mcve] to illustrate your problem in more details.

Comment: @Nikita I just want to launch connect() on a background thread, thats all.

Comment: There is not standard method `connect` with no arguments at `QMainWindow` class. Looks like it's implemented in your `MainWindow` class, you should post implementation here. Otherwise it's not possible to understand how to help you.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it, for example creating a QRunnable and run that in a threadpool, implement a QThread, or you could just run your method in a thread with [QtConcurrent::run](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrent.html#run), e.g.

```
auto future = QtConcurrent::run([&window] { window.connect(); })
```

The return QFuture object is a handle that you can use to wait for the thread to finish, retrieve results if the function returns something etc.

Side note: Since QMainWindow/QWidget is derived from QObject, and there is QObject::connect with various overloads, it probably is a good idea to rename your connect method.